# Is it possible to edit a project once is published on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm testing an application I just published using the free option that Azure gives us.

In this process I found out that I need to make a change to a Controller (ASP.NET Core 2.0) and I've been looking for the options to do so.

I've encountered with Azure App Service Editor and I'm reading some documentation about it. However, it does not seem the way to do this kind of change since I can't access the *.cs files thru this service. This is the list of files that are shown:

[image]

So, my **question** is:

Is there a way to edit these files (controllers, views) with Azure App Service Editor?
If no, what would be the way to reflect this changes on my already published application? Also, in the case the answer is "republish the project", is it possible to do so without alter the information contained in the database that has been added during this test process and only update the modified files?

I apoligize if these questions are very basic but I'm just getting started to know about Azure. Thanks in advance.

**How I publish it:**

In order to publish this project I used the option Visual Studio gives us:

[image]

Now, if I go to the same option, this windows shows up:

[image]

**Question:** If I hit the 'Publish' button I believe it will republish, the whole project, correct (the database included)? If this is the case, I believe there will be conflicts about the databases, since I have already information in the project published and other information in the local project. Is it possible to reflect the update for everything but the databases?

Comment: how do you publish it there in the first place..? you can edit it if you have the permissions to push / publish the updated code from your local after recompile.. so `Yes` you can ..assuming you have the rights/permissions

Comment: @MethodMan I added information about how it was published. Yes, I did it, but if I do what I know I believe I might republish everything including the databases creating conflict between the database online and the database I have locally and I would like to avoid that and only update what is needed or don't touch the databases at least

Comment: most publishing functionality like ClickOnce take for example, have their own versioning, do you use any version control like TFS.. I would make a backup of what's working first if you don't .. then publish the changes otherwise consult with an expert or your team lead

Comment: I haven't seen that option for Azure, yet. Will explore it tho. And well, no, there is no team lead :) only me. Thanks

Comment: if you are unsure of changing something 1st rule of thumb, always have a backup you can revert back to and invest in some reliable version control software like `TFS`

Comment: @MethodMan while I am also an advocate of source control, OP is concerned about **_the information contained in the database_** which obviously can't be in source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't update the files there as this is a compiled web app, so you have to publish the update.

I'm assuming you're using EntityFramework and originally publishing the database via the web publish.

If you click "settings" on the publish dialogue, on the second page (settings tab) you'll see the options for publishing the database.

Here you'll see options as to whether to update the database during deployment, this I believe is to apply migrations. But if you uncheck these it should not update your database at all.

You should verify this after saving the publish by looking at the generated publish profile (you **don't** have to do a publish to see this)

It will be located at "YourApp\Properties\PublishProfiles" and should have been added to your solution, and will be called something like "Your App - Web Deploy.pubxml"

Within this you will see a `<PublishDatabaseSettings>` section, where the `Enabled` properties should be set to `False`

However I would advice that before publishing any update:

- **Test** the deployment to a new server
- **Back up** the database before deploying and test you can restore from it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll explore your solution as soon as possible!